# Line by line check for large amount of keywords with python

Tags: python, regex, list, csv

I am iterating through many csv files with 1000 to 3000 lines checking each line whether one of 70000 key words is inherited in a text of 140 characters. My problem at the moment is, that my code runs extremely slow. I guess because of the many iterations. I am relatively new programer and not sure what is the best way to speed up. It took 2 hours to check one entire file and there are still many many I need to go through. My logic at the moment is: import csv as list of lists -> for each list in list take the first element and search for each of the 70000 keywords whether it is mentioned.

Currently my code looks like the following:

```
import re
import csv


def findname(lst_names,text):
  for name in lst_names:
  name_match = re.search(r'@'+str(name), text)
  if name_match:
    return name 

lst_users = importusr_lst('users.csv') #defined function to import 700000 keywords
lst_successes = []
with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
  filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
  content = []

  for row in filereader:
    content.append(row)
  if len(content)>1:
    for row in content:
      hit = []
      mentioned = findname(lst_names, row[0]) #row[0] is the text of 140 characters

      if mentioned:
        hit = row[1:7]
        hit.append(mentioned)
        lst_successes.append(hit)

return lst_successes
```

The input is a list of tweets with data about this tweet. One row contains the following information:

```
Tweet_text,Tweet_id,Tweet_date,Tweet_fav_count,Tweet_retweet_count,Replied_to user_id,Replied_to_stats_id,author_name,user_name
```

One example could be:

```
"This is an awesome tweet @username.",576819939086041089,2015-03-14,18:59:24,0,2,4,jjwniemzok,jjwniemzok
```

Keywords are usernames in Twitter. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This looks like a task for a full text search engine instead of a nested loop. Could you give sample input and sample keywords?

Comment: Input is a list of tweets with data about this tweet. One row contains the following information: [Tweet_text, Tweet_id, Tweet_date, Tweet_fav_count, Tweet_retweet_count, Replied to user(id), Replied to stats(id), author_name, user_name]. One example could be: ["This is an awesome tweet @Tomalak." ,576819939086041089, 2015-03-14 18:59:24,0,2,4,jjwniemzok,jjwniemzok] keywords are usernames in twitter. Does that help? I need multiple cells of the row.

Comment: When you say "for each list in list take the first element and search..."  does that mean you just want to search for the key words against each entry of the first column of the csv file..  and that these entries are 140 character strings ?

Comment: so then each Tweet_text is 140 characters long? and you are trying to match user names with there tweets ?

Comment: Yes exactly. first column are tweets of 140 characters. I want to find out whether one of many users is mentioned in that tweet.

Comment: Does a tweet always end with the user name you are searching for e.g. ```'whoops I don't twitter @dermen'``` ?

Comment: How about `multiprocessing`? It isn't the best way to go about this, serial optimisation is crucial always, but doing this stuff in parallel will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make `lst_names` into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), if it isn't one already, in order to have expected constant time `name in lst_names` checks. Then for each tweet, instead of iterating through all the names and looking for them specifically, look for any name:

```
names_set = set(lst_names)
# ...
name_match = re.search('@(\w+)\b', text)
if name_match:
  name = name_match.group(1)
  if name in names_set:
    return name
```

(I'm assuming twitter names are `\w+` here).

You might also want to compile the regex in advance; see Tomalak's answer.

Comment: worked extremely well. only change I had to do is to improve logic for tweets with multiple names: inline `name_match = re.findall('@(\w+)', text)
  if name_match:
    for name in name_match:
      if name in lst_names:
        return name`

Answer (score 0):

I will make some test tweet data. I assume here that a tweet user name is immediately preceded by an '@' symbol in the tweet text, e.g. a tweet might read `'something cool @someone1 @someone2 something else cool @someone3'`. I will make some test data:

```
import numpy as np
import string
tweet_templates = [['askdjaklsd {0} akdjsakd {1}', 2], ['alskalkals {0}',1], ['{0} kadksjdss {1} {2}',3]  ]
some_names      = array( [ '@'+''.join( random.sample( string.letters , 5) ) for i in xrange( 70000 )] ) # large number of poss user names
template_i      = np.random.randint( 0,3,30000 ) # 30000 tweets
tweets          = [ tweet_templates[t][0].format( *some_names[  np.random.randint( 0 ,len(some_names ), tweet_templates[t][1] )] ) for t in template_i]
```

In your case when loading the text from csv I would use numpy.loadtxt (personal choice):

```
#tweet_data = np.loadtxt( 'tweet_file.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str) 
# there are options to ignore headers etc.
#tweets = tweet_data[:,0] # first column
```

Now, that we have data, isolate the names in each row:

```
tweets_split = map( lambda x : x.split(), tweets )
tweet_names = map( lambda y: filter( lambda x : x[0] == '@', y ), tweets_split )
print tweet_names
#[['@msUnu', '@KvUqA'], ['@GknKr'], ['@Hxbfe'],  ...
tweet_names = map( lambda y: map( lambda x : x.split('@')[-1], y ), tweet_names )
print tweet_names
#[['msUnu', 'KvUqA'], ['GknKr'], ['Hxbfe'],
```

Then make a list where each element is a sublist `[ name, tweet_row]` where `name` is the twitter user's name, and `tweet_row` is the row where the name was found in the `tweets` data.

```
tweet_names_info = [ map( lambda n : [ n,ind ] , tweet_names[ind] ) for ind in xrange( len(tweets) ) ]
tweet_names_info = [ sl for sublist in tweet_names_info for sl in sublist]
```

Group this list according to the names:

```
from itertools import groupby
tweet_names_grouped = [ [k, list( np.array(list(g))[:,1].astype(int))] for k,g in groupby( tweet_names_info, lambda x: x[0] ) ]
tweet_names_rows  = dict( tweet_names_grouped )
```

Now you have a dictionary where the keys are the twitter user names, and the values are the row numbers of the corresponding tweets. It should be easy to compare this dictionary object to your list of users:

```
tweeters = tweet_names_rows.keys()
#lst_users = importusr_lst('users.csv') 
#^ your function, I assume it loads a 1D array, I will make up some user names
lst_users  = array( [ ''.join( random.sample( string.letters , 5) ) for i in xrange( 130000 )] )
users_who_tweeted = list( set(tweeters).intersection(set(lst_users)) )

if users_who_tweeted:
    for u in users_who_tweeted:
        u_text = [  tweets[i]  for i in tweet_names_rows[u] ]
        print 'USER %s WAS ON TWITTER:'% u
        print '\n'.join( u_text), '\n'

#USER ZeHLA WAS ON TWITTER:
#alskalkals @ZeHLA 

#USER jaZuG WAS ON TWITTER:
#@mjLTG kadksjdss @jaZuG @DJNjv 

#USER UVzSs WAS ON TWITTER:
#@tnGrH kadksjdss @DOBij @UVzSs 
#...
#...
```

Comment: Good idea, you pretty much definitely want to try and sort the data somehow so you don't have to iterate as much and sorting on a user basis makes sense.